# Minutes going over 60 in Stopwatch

Tags: ios, swift

sorry if this sounds like a noob question. I am building a stopwatch app for iPhone. The label displays hh:mm:ss. The seconds properly reset to 0 when they reach 60 and start again from 0 but the minutes go above 60. Here's the code:

```
var elapsedTime = NSTimeInterval()

@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject)
{
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "fireStopWatch", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    startTime = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)

}

func fireStopWatch()
   {
    var currentTime:NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
    elapsedTime = currentTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)



    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime/60)
    elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)
    let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
    elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)
    let hours = UInt8(elapsedTime/3600.0)
    elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(hours) * 3600)

    let strHours = hours > 9 ? String(hours):"0" + String(hours)
    let strMinutes = minutes > 9 ? String(minutes):"0" + String(minutes)
    let strSeconds = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds):"0" + String(seconds)


    displayTimeLabel.text = "\(strHours):\(strMinutes)"
    displaySecondsLabel.text = "\(strSeconds)"



}
```

What's happening with the seconds that isn't happening with minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the hours above the minutes so it gets subtracted out (just like how you have minutes above seconds)

```
let hours = UInt8(elapsedTime/3600.0)
elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(hours) * 3600)
let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime/60)
elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)
let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)
```

Comment: I do not know why this answer was down voted (perhaps the voter could leave a comment). I prefer integer arithmetic to avoid any floating point precision problems, but I don't think that would be an issue in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Your line

```
let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime/60)
```

computes the total number of minutes, not the number of minutes "within the hour".
You could fix that by subtracting `60 * hours` later.

But I find it easier to start with the lowest unit (seconds) and then compute the higher
units (minutes, hours, ...) using integer division and the *remainder operator* `%`:

```
let totalSeconds = Int(elapsedTime)  // Total number of seconds as an integer
let seconds = totalSeconds % 60      // Seconds to display
let totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60 // Total number of minutes
let minutes = totalMinutes % 60      // Minutes to display
let hours = totalMinutes / 60        // Hours to display
```

This could also be easily expanded to more units such as days.

Note that

```
let strHours = hours > 9 ? String(hours):"0" + String(hours)
let strMinutes = minutes > 9 ? String(minutes):"0" + String(minutes)
let strSeconds = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds):"0" + String(seconds)
displayTimeLabel.text = "\(strHours):\(strMinutes)"
displaySecondsLabel.text = "\(strSeconds)"
```

can be simplified using string formatting functions:

```
displayTimeLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", hours, minutes)
displaySecondsLabel.text = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
```